# How can I logout (Identity) in code in a Blazor server app

Tags: blazor, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

In my code I handle a DbUpdateConcurrencyException and for the case of updating a user's account, and the user no longer exists, I want to log them out - as they are no longer a valid user.

Granted, not a biggie because this should be rare and any page they try to go to will not accept them as they no longer have a claim. But its cleaner to log them out.

I can't use the SignInManager in Blazor. It requires a POST to LogOut.cshtml. So, what's my options?

Answer (score 0):

I use the [Cookie Authentication in Blazor server](https://github.com/Kamalifar/BlazorServerCookieAuthentication-master). For login and logout, I use the `.cshtml` file. In the logout page, I use the below code:

```
@page
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies

@functions
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
    {
        if (HttpContext.User!=null)
        {
            <p>You successfully logout.</p>
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }
        return Redirect("~/Login");
    }
}
```

You can see it in [my repo](https://github.com/Kamalifar/BlazorServerCookieAuthentication-master/blob/main/Pages/Security/logout.cshtml).
I call the `logout.cshtml` in a blazor component ([LoginDisplay](https://github.com/Kamalifar/BlazorServerCookieAuthentication-master/blob/main/Pages/Security/LoginDisplay.razor)) such as below:

```
<a class="logout-btn login-btn-improved" href="Security/Logout">Logout</a>
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: I can't find the page but Microsoft says that LogOut needs to happen on a POST, not a GET for security reasons. And they do show it implemented that way at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio